# Get-MailboxFolderStatistics shows only number

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-online

I try to create a simple Powershell Exchange Online Shell to get total items in specific folder of mailbox.

```
$myJob1 = ((Get-Mailbox -Identity abc@mail.com | Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -FolderScope DeletedItems | Select ItemsInFolder)| Out-String).Trim()
if($myJob1 -eq "5000")
{
    Write-Host("Equal")
}
else
{
    Write-Host("Not equal")
}
```

But the result of $myJob1 always return like that:

```
ItemsInFolder
-------------
         3675
```

Instead I just need only number 3675 and nothing more.

How can I fixed that with my code, please.

Comment: `$myJob1 = Get-Mailbox -Identity abc@mail.com | Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -FolderScope DeletedItems | Select -Expand ItemsInFolder`

Comment: In short: [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) by default returns _a `[pscustomobject]` instance_ that has the _requested properties_ - even when you're only asking for a _single_ property. To get only that property's _value_, use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter instead of the (possibly positionally implied) `-Property` parameter. See the linked duplicate for details and alternatives, notably the ability to simply use `(...).SomeProperty`